# Read audio file from s3 directly in python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, audio, librosa

i want to read audio file from s3 directly  in python.

First, I record audio, here is my blob settings

```
blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type: 'audio/wav'});
```

then using django i uploaded this file to s3

```
req=request.POST.get('data')
d=req.split(",")[1]
file_content_io = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(d))
s3_path='audio/file_name_{}.wav'.format(random.randint(0,99))
default_storage.save(s3_path, file_content_io)
```

then i download file directly

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(file) as response:
    audio=BytesIO(response.read())
    speech_array=read(audio)
```

Now its giving me following error

```
ValueError: File format b'OggS' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.
```

Any solution? I also tried librosa, thats also not working. The only thing i want to read file directly without saving in disk

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are willing to switch from urllib to boto3, but I resolved the issue of loading .wav files from S3 directly into Python using boto3:

```
import io
import boto3
import librosa

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
for file in  bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='your_prefix'):
    bin_obj = file.get()['Body'].read()
    data = librosa.load(io.BufferedReader(io.BytesIO(bin_obj)))
```